# How to extract SSO cookie when using scalaj http library

Tags: scala, scalaj-http

I have a `HTTP` response. I am trying to get the value for one of the header from it using `scala`.
My code looks similar to below:

```scala
import scalaj.http.Http

val result = Http("http:///sample.com")
  .postData("""{"Username":"user1","password":"pass"""")
  .header("Content-Type", "application")
  .header("Accept", "text/plain")
val headers = result.headers.mkString

println("Headers: " + headers)
```

The headers look similar to below:

```
Cache-Control -> Vector(no-Store)
Content-Type -> Vector(text/html;charset=ISO-8859-l)
Set-Cookie -> Vector(SESSIONID=D122334;path=/a/b/c;SSO=000112233445)
```

Out of this header, I want to extract SSO value alone. Using below code, I am able to print them properly.

```
for((k,v) <- result.headers) println(s"key: $k\nvalue: $v\n")
```

Getting following result:

```
key: Cache-Control
value: Vector(no-Store)

key: Content-Type
value: Vector(text/html;charset=ISO-8859-l)

key: Set-Cookie
value: Vector(SESSIONID=D122334;path=/a/b/c;SSO=000112233445)
```

I want to extract the data for `SSO` under key `Set-Cookie` alone.
I am aware of how to achieve this using python

I am pretty new to Scala. Can some one please help me out here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `cookies` methods and filter cookie by name

```scala
  val ssoToken = Http("http:///sample.com")
    .postData("""???""")
    .header("Content-Type", "application")
    .header("Accept", "text/plain")
    .asBytes
    .cookies
    .find(_.getName == "SSO")
    .map(_.getValue)
```

You will get `Some("tokenValue")` when token is found, if you want to get it as `String`, you can do the following

```scala
ssoToken.getOrElse(sys.error("SSO Token not found"))
```

It will throw an exception if token is not found

Comment: Tried it...Along with SSO value, i am getting `Some()`. 
Output looks similar to below: `Some(<SSO token value>)`. Any idea why some is coming?

Comment: Yes, your token is found and returned as `Some("tokenValue"`)

Comment: is there anyway to get token without some?

Comment: you get an `Option` back, you can use `map`, `foreach`, `getOrElse` or pattern match to handle it. See my edit for one way of handling it